# Are there any dicta/guidelines about the use of the mandatory tags on child metas?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

It's been mentioned a number of times that users should feel free to post basically whatever on their local metas (instead of bringing them here to Meta.SE), since the Powers That Be (devs? community team?) monitor all the child metas.

My understanding is that this is at least partially automated - the Powers That Be can view feature requests across all metas, or bug reports across all metas, or what not. (At least, I sure hope it is! Having to trawl 100+ meta sites manually sounds terrible!)

This being the case, are there any rules or guidelines about what kinds of questions should be tagged with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on child metas? I mean, obviously bug reports should be tagged with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), and proposals for new functionality locally or globally should be tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but what about e.g. requests for a site's moderators to do something like [synonymize](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/1908) or [rename](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/128/1908) a tag, or [proposals for local policy changes](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/108/1908)?

The reason I'm asking is that I noticed that a global-♦ person came by and removed the feature-request tag from [a question on a child meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/963/revisions) - so I was basically wondering if incorrectly-tagged posts on child metas are causing trouble further upstream, and if so, what users of child metas should do to mitigate this.

Comment: Given the attention a lot of site-specific bugs and FRs get, I'm not confident they can easily view them across all sites.

Answer (score 3):

That looks to have been removed because the OP tagged with both `discussion` and `feature-request` - this isn't necessary (`feature-request` will generate discussion if necessary, making `discussion` redundant).

The requirements for the mandatory tags are shown in the watermark of the tags textbox:

[image]

Possibly the watermark text should have the "*at least*" removed because none of those tags need to be used together.

Answer (score -1):

About the linked case: the feature is the ability to have tag synonyms, and it already exists. So it wasn't feature request, just a request to add such tag synonym.

Here on MSE we have [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) for this, maybe better have it across all child metas as well.

Anyway, no official guidelines except the wiki of the tags, it's common sense and in case users make mistakes it's the role of the long time members to retag properly.

Comment: If it was common sense, I wouldn't need to ask this question in the first place. Both of the child metas I frequent ([meta.anime.SE] and [meta.japanese.SE]) have multiple questions tagged [tag:feature-request] that are actually about tag synonyms or tag renames or other non-feature-requests, and I'm sure this is the case at many other smaller child metas.

Comment: Well, no harm done if one choose the wrong tag. Those "global diamonds" as you call them (Community Managers is the official name) sometimes clean up stuff just to have clean table, keep in mind that the feature requests and bug reports are their TODO-list in the long range. So basically if something can be done by ordinary users or moderators and does not require code change, it's not a bug or feature request.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm getting at - is there anything we should be doing so that they don't _have_ to clean stuff up? (Also, not all global-♦ users are Community Managers, are they? Some of them are devs and C-levels and whatnot.)

Comment: We can retag ourselves (even with low rep, one can suggest a retag) and yeah, there are developers and Jeff Atwood who is a special case these days. What is "C-level"?

Comment: CEO, CTO, COO, CFO, and all of that. Chief [something] officers.

Comment: Oh, in one word "management". Well, it's not consistent. Joel does have diamond in most sites, but as far as I know, he never used it. [Michael Pryor](http://stackexchange.com/users/198/michael-pryor?tab=accounts) the CFO on the other hand doesn't have any diamond anywhere. He can ask for one of course if needed for some reason.